# time.time() or time.perf_counter() — which is faster?

Tags: python, performance, optimization, time

Context: I'm implementing a memory cache with TTLs in my Python project, and it has to withstand considerable throughput. To determine when a cache record goes stale, I save it with a timestamp, and when I retrieve it later I check this timestamp against the current time. If the difference is above the threshold, the record is stale and should be discarded.

Question: `time.time()` or `time.perf_counter()` — which function returns its value faster? Is the difference considerable or negligible?

Answer (score 19):

The choice between `time.time()` and `time.perf_counter()` depends on the context in which you will use the function. That's because each function deals with a different "type of time".

`time.time()` deals with absolute time, i.e., "real-world time" (the type of time we're used to). It's measured from a fixed point in the past. According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time), `time.time()` returns:

> (...) the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number.

`time.perf_counter()`, on the other hand, deals with relative time, which has no defined relationship to real-world time (i.e., the relationship is unknown to us and depends on several factors). It's measured using a CPU counter and, as specified in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter), should only be used to measure time intervals:

> The reference point of the returned value is undefined, so that only
> the difference between the results of consecutive calls is valid.

Because of that, `time.perf_counter()` is mostly used to compare performance.

---

That said, I don't think there is any point in comparing the speed of those two functions. They were designed to be used for different things - you should pick the one that best suits your use case. Quoting a comment by  @Martijn Pieters:

> Sometimes you need a hammer, sometimes you need a screwdriver. You
> don't ask if one or the other is faster; you either have a nail or a
> screw. Trying to use a screwdriver on a nail may work,
> but is not the best choice.

From what I've gathered from your comment, you're probably better off using `time.perf_counter()`, since your focus is in relative time and not in "real-world time". In such a context, `time.perf_counter()` is probably going to be more precise, because it uses:

> (...) a clock with the highest available resolution to measure a short
> duration.

Comment: @Talendar: No, you didn't understand my use-case right. I am dealing with "timestamps" only in a sense that they are points in time used to calculate the length of timespan between them, but there is no reason to limit them to points of real-world time. Relative system-specific time is fine too, as long as its second is as long as a real-world second. (Yes, I wil not trade these "timestamps" between different systems, so system-specific is fine.)
Your whole lenghty answer will be much appreciated by those in search of such information, but it is completely irrelevant in my case.

Comment: @Владислав Савенков: I've updated my answer, I hope it will be more useful to you now. I'm sorry I can't help more. Cheers!

Answer (score 10):

### Update

Both `time` and `perf_counter` perform equally and no conclusion can be drawn about which is faster with a reliable statistical result across all platforms, please run the benchmark yourself on your target platform before drawing conclusions

Here are the commands to reproduce the same on your machine

```
python -m timeit -s "from time import perf_counter as time" -n 10000000 "time()"
python -m timeit -s "from time import time" -n 10000000 "time()"
```

#### Windows 11, Python 3.10, AMD ryzen 5 3500U

perf_counter:

```py
10000000 loops, best of 5: 132 nsec per loop
10000000 loops, best of 5: 126 nsec per loop
```

time:

```
10000000 loops, best of 5: 69.6 nsec per loop
10000000 loops, best of 5: 75.9 nsec per loop
```

<s>We can conclude that `time.time()` is nearly twice as fast than `time.perf_counter()`

However the magnitude of the difference is very low, ~56 nanoseconds. 

To put that into perspective it is only ~168 clock cycles slower on a 3ghz cpu</s>